# Rebase part of branch to a commit

Tags: git, rebase

My `master` looks like this:

```
A --- B --- C (master)
```

I branched from `B` and made some changes on branch `1`:

```
A --- B --- C (master)
       \
        \-- D --- E --- F (1)
```

Then I branched from `F` and made some changes on branch `2`:

```
A --- B --- C (master)
       \
        \-- D --- E --- F (1)
                         \
                          \-- G --- H --- I (2)
```

Then I applied my changes on `1` onto `master` by merge squashing `D`, `E`, `F` into `master`, where `K` is the result of merge squashing `D`, `E` and `F`:

```
A --- B --- C --- K (master)
       \       /  |  \
        \-- D --- E --- F (1)
                         \
                          \-- G --- H --- I (2)
```

Then, I want to rebase `G`, `H`, `I` onto `K`, so that it looks like this:

```
A --- B --- C --- K (master)
                   \
                    \-- G' --- H' --- I' (2)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, like usual.

```
git rebase --onto master f branch2
```

Comment: Is git smart enough to ignore `D`, `E` and `F` while rebasing?

Comment: Err, good catch - it will if you give it the adjusted command. :-)